# determine the user who run the current process

Tags: c, linux, root

I just wonder, how can we determine if the current process is running as root or not. after searching on google, I found out that Linux has a field called "current" that I can use to determine who is running a particular process. I try to use

```
current->uid == 0
```

However, when I try to compile my code I get this error

```
struct task_structâ has no member named âuidâ
```

did I do something wrong? additionally, is it true if the process run as root, the uid always equal to zero? thanks

Comment: The `current->***` variable is only visible from kernel-space. In user space you should use `getuid()`

Comment: Just use `getuid() == 0` or `geteuid() == 0`.

Comment: BTW: the getuid() and geteuid() functions are actually systemcalls that inspect the current->[e]uid fields (for the current process), and report them back to the user process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a process ,it have 3 kind of user ID:

1.Actual user  ID

--> most of time is who we are, the man who login , while the root process has some way to change it.

Use `getuid()` to get this user ID.

2.Effective user ID

-->This ID decide the access limits. `exce` function can set this ID ,and if it didn't, this user ID is the same as actual user ID.

Use `geteuid()` to get this ID

3.Saved settings user ID

--> it copyed from the effective user ID by `exec` function. No function to get this ID's current value.At least , I don't know.

So

```
how can we determine if the current process is running as root or not
```

If you mean running **as** root ,use `geteuid() == 0` is better, just my opinion.